# ECP Access Denied?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I'm having an issue with Microsoft Exchange Control Panel.

I have 2 servers with Exchange installed, both have the Client Access role, however only one has the Mailbox and Hub Transport roles. When I log in to the server hosting the Exchange Mailbox and Hub Transport roles, I am able to access the ECP webapp no problem. However, on the Internet-facing server (with only Client Access) I get the following error:

`Sorry! Access denied. You don't have permission to open this page. If you're a new user or were recently assigned credentials, please wait 15 minutes and try again. If the problem persists, contact your administrator.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... After the third attempt rebooting, everything started working perfectly. No idea what the problem was, but it's fixed now. Disaster averted.